# How to call useQuery only once with graphQL?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

So I am working on react with GraphQL and I want to call my useQuery only once ,but the problem here is that it executes everytime when page refreshes thus giving the 404 local host error.

Aim :- Want to call this query only once.

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(getAllData);
```

I have also tried to achieve this by specifying the condition with useLazyQuery but still no success in that..

```
let check=true;
 useEffect(() => {
    if (check) {
       check=false;
      getEndpoint();
    }
    
  },[]);

  const [getEndpoint, { data, error, loading }] = useLazyQuery(getAllData);
```

I am not able to figure any ways how to achieve that..Any Help would be appreciated !

Comment: Why not put it in a `useEffect` like you are with `getEndpoint`?  Controlling execution over re-renders based on dependencies is `useEffect`'s purpose

Comment: Also your `check` boolean probably belongs in some state

Comment: you can't call useQuery inside useEffect...it has to be called outside the scope of hooks

Comment: Sorry, you're right and I see now your problem is probably that `check`.  Your idiom for `useLazyQuery` and putting it in the `useEffect` is correct.  The `check` variable is your problem because it's going to reset to `true` on every re-render.  Put it in state `const [check, setCheck] = useState(true)` and replace your `check = false` with `setCheck(false)`.

Comment: @possum Yup I also tried that but still query was calling it several times.....

Comment: @AlexPandianmadhar were you able to resolve this?